# What is the difference between Combo box and drop down list in asp.net Ajax Control Toolkit

Tags: asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu, combobox

What is the difference between Combo box and drop down list in asp.net Ajax Control Toolkit

Comment: Maybe the Ajax Control Toolkit is taking liberties with control naming (I'm not familiar with the toolkit), but drop down lists don't let you type in your own text instead of selecting from the list.  A combo box does (it's a 'combo' of an edit box with a drop down list).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between drop down box and combo box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176297/is-there-any-difference-between-drop-down-box-and-combo-box)

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET DropDownList and the AjaxControlToolkit ComboBox are both very similar. In fact, the AjaxControlToolkit's ComboBox derives from the same base class as the ASP.NET DropDownList. The [ASP.NET AJAX site gives a good summary](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/combobox/combobox.aspx#ctl00_SampleContent_Description_ToggleImage) of the differences and similarities between the two controls:

> Working with a ComboBox in code is also a lot like working with a
>   DropDownList. It has all of the same properties and events as a
>   DropDownList, with a few additional ComboBox-specific properties and
>   events. Firstly, it can be configured to either prevent or allow
>   user-typed text that does not match an item in the list. When
>   user-typed text does match an item in the list, the ComboBox can also
>   be configured to auto-complete the text based on the first matched
>   item in the list, to show the list and highlight the first matched
>   item, or to do both simultaneously. When user-typed text does not
>   match an item in the list, the ComboBox raises ItemInserting and
>   ItemInserted events which can be handled during postback. **Other than
>   these special behaviors, the ComboBox behaves essentially like a
>   DropDownList.**

In summary, a ComboBox is primarily a DropDownList that allows you to type text into the control in addition to simply using the dropdown arrow to select an existing item from the list.