# listbox display manipulation --highlight first 3 items(not selected row)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, listbox

I am working with wpf and C# , using Visual studio for an application development. I have the data in my listbox listed (data taken from database). I want to manipulate the listbox display such that, either the 1st 3 items in listbox are highlighted(not the selected row) or may be draw a lkine after 1st 3 items.. or anything that could draw the users attention to the 1st 3 items of listbox... I know its obvious, but may not be always obvious when i populate data using fuzzy search... So please dont ask me why I am doing this..
But if u have any kinda info abt how to do this, or how to manipulate listbox display please share :)

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For WPF (listbox gets items from database)

In my example i'm adding country names from table countries, to the listbox.

Then, i'm highlighting first 3 entries of the listbox:

```
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db_myDB;Integrated Security=true");
            SqlDataReader myReader=null;

            int i = 0;

            myConnection.Open();



             myReader = new SqlCommand("select  countryname from dbo.countries", myConnection).ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {

                    ListBoxItem li = new ListBoxItem();
                    li.Content = myReader.GetString(0);
                    listBox1.Items.Add(li);

                    if(i<3)
                    li.Background = Brushes.Blue;

                    i++;
                }

              myConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a `ListBox` Control is a list of elements, you could populate it's source of data and then highlight the three top elements in some way.

See this question for reference on how to color the elements :)
[C# : changing listbox row color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554609/c-sharp-changing-listbox-row-color)

Comment: Can I know the reason of the downvote so I can enhance my answer? ^^

Comment: While I didn't down vote you, I can see that it was because of your poor quality answer. Saying *you could populate it's source of data and then highlight the three top elements in some way* is *not* answering the question. Furthermore, this is a WPF question and you provided a link to a WinForms question, so if you ask me, you're lucky to have only received one down vote. Your answer certainly doesn't deserve the up vote that you got. Finally, your answer consists of just two sentences... I think you had plenty of scope to *enhance your answer* even without the down voter leaving a comment.

Comment: (That *was* meant to be constructive criticism, like you asked and hopefully I did not offend you.)

Comment: @Sheridan None offense taken, I'm pretty new to this website and comments like yours help me understand how things are made around here :)
Also, I had totally overlooked the tag... thanks for pointing it out to me ^^

Comment: That's a great attitude to have @Landir. If you have the time, then you can find out lots of valuable information from the Stack Overflow [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) that will enable you to get the most out of this great website.

Comment: that was so nice of you both, and even I am a new bie and I guess I was waiting for such an info of Help Centre.. Thanks

Comment: @Landir I can't say I have enough domain knowledge to know whether this answer is useful or not, but I find it curious that you haven't edited or deleted this answer in response to Sheridan's comment, despite replying to it and showing no disagreement with what was said.

Answer (score -2):

For Asp.Net :-

You can change the colour of the items to be highlighted

You can put this in Page_Load

```
ListBox1.Items[0].Attributes.Add("style", "color: #F00");
ListBox1.Items[1].Attributes.Add("style", "color: #F00");
ListBox1.Items[2].Attributes.Add("style", "color: #F00");
```

Where ListBox1 is the name of your List Box

Comment: Do you know how this can be done in a combobox.. ? Also I am using Itemsource to bind data to combobox

Comment: @user3218207 You mean for DropDownList, Isn't it..!! (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176297/is-there-any-difference-between-drop-down-box-and-combo-box)

Ok then you can write this code 

 foreach (ListItem myItem in DropDownList1.Items)
            {
                myItem.Attributes.Add("style", "color:red");
            }

Comment: @Gk_999, I think OP wants [`ComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx) as he clearly states _I am working with wpf_ and question is tagged _WPF_ not _ASP.NET_. Don't know why you got upvote, let alone accepted answer as this won't event compile in WPF unless user tagged question wrong.

Comment: @dkozl Thanx 4 informing my mistake, I've added another answer w.r.t. wpf